# Is .indexWhere() async?

Tags: flutter, dart

As indexWhere() searches through potentially large Lists to find the matching index, is this an async operation?

And if so is there some way to await it? e.g. similar to Future.forEach

Answer (score 1):

Since the method does not return a `Future` but an `int`, then the method is synchronous:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html

I also want to point out that asynchronous code in Dart are not the same as the code is running in another thread. Since we are talking about finding a index inside a `List`, then you can be fairly sure that this operation can only be done in a single thread since we need to prevent modifications of the `List` when we are making the search.